# systemd timer to start .sh script daily at 2 different hours

Tags: systemd

I have a *bourne shell script* (at my NAS) that handles the *ffmpeg* recording of all my *ipcams*. For switching the record time (etc) of some cams, that sh script should be restarted daily at 2 different hours (`07:00am` and `10:00pm`), which is configured in the bash script and works well.

1. To start the sh script, I make use of *systemd* with the following .service file:

   `[Unit]
   Description=record ipcams
   After=tmp.mount network.target
   Requires=network.target
   RequiresMountsFor=/media/USB2`

   `[Service]
   Type=forking
   PIDFile=/var/run/cams_record.pid
   ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/media/USB2/movie/cams/cams_record.sh'
   TimeoutStopSec=1
   Restart=always`

   `[Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target`

So far so good. Now what I actually want, is to restart that script file daily at `07:00am` and `10:00pm` (or restart the previous mentioned .service at those two times) thus I thought to make use of a *systemd timer*. I created such a timer for `07:00 am` (with the option: `OnCalender=07:00`)

Question is: having a (permanently running) service, how do I restart that service (and thus the script file) at `07:00am` and `22:00pm`. I can of course make use of 2 systemd timers (1 for `07:00am` and 1 for `10:00pm`), but is there a possibility to combine these; i.e. using 1 systemd timer for both times.

Comment: I think you can combine timer and templates : see https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/

Answer (score 2):

With a templates timers, you can do something like this

```
cat test@.timer 
[Unit]
Description=test

[Timer]
OnCalendar=%i:00
Unit=test.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Then :

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and

```
systemctl start test@07.service
systemctl start test@22.service
```

Source : https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/ and https://jason.the-graham.com/2013/03/06/how-to-use-systemd-timers/

Comment: Thx good idea. Didn't know of the %i
I also "found" that 

OnCalendar=7,22:00

als work

Answer (score 1):

You can use several **OnCalendar** in one timer, see documentation https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#OnCalendar=

```
[Unit]
Description=test

[Timer]
OnCalendar=07:00
OnCalendar=10:00
Unit=test.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```